# C# changing XSD's problem

Tags: c#, xsd

I am trying to implement an ISO standard which by summary has the following:

1. There are `operations` (like an action in MVC)
2. There are respective `request` and `response` per operation
3. These `requests` and `responses` have corresponding `XSD`'s
4. These `XSD`'s are changing per year (as per my observation)

Here are my challenges for now:

1. `XSD` to `C#` classes generation (via VS command line) are so much pain. There are certain classes like `Header` and `Enum`'s which are common to these `XSD`s but are getting generated separately.
2. I only need specific properties from each `response`, the other values will be mapped to its `response` as return values. Which creates a conflict because of my problem in #1

   > mapping the header from the request to response is not straightforward
   >   because they are of different classes. Same for other classes and enum
   >   values.
3. I can manually map these values from `request` to `response` of all the `operations` that I need. But now my problem is  the item #4 from my summary above. These `XSD`'s are getting updates per year. I saw some considerable amount of change from last year's version to now like new values added to enum and new elements in XML.

Here are my thoughts for next action:

1. Is there any `XSD` to `C#` classes generator which is smart enough not to duplicate the common classes and enumerations? This will primarily solve my problem as the mapper will be easily created. But doing it manually is an issue of deadlines and also the changing `XSD`'s.
2. If #1 is not a feasible solution, I am thinking of `PropertyCopiers` which can map values from different classes. But I haven't searched of such copiers that can map nested classes (deep property copiers). I would only rely on `propertyNames` which I can say is not reliable enough and reflection is quite slow.
3. My last resort is doing the mapper manually like:

   DifferentClass1.SamePropertyName1 = DifferentClass2.SamePropertyName1

   and just do another mapper again next year when the next version comes.

Comment: What is the top-level purpose of the ISO standard?  To facilitate building web scrapers?  Create Internet machine middleware communicating via HTTP?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is to standardize the format of messages between entities.

Comment: you want to automate the annual job of updating your c# client? instead see if there is a published client for the api

Comment: @Ewan sorry for the late reply. I haven't really thought of automation. My problem was just it was too hassle to map nested properties from `Type1` to `Type2` every year. And this problem was caused by the way `XSD.exe` (of visual studio) generates `C#` classes. But as I continue my research, I began to realize that this is a common problem for others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I continue my research for days, given that `XML` and `XSD`'s has been long on `enterprise products`, my problem has been been experienced by other developers too.

> 2. If #1 is not a feasible solution, I am thinking of PropertyCopiers which can map values from different classes. But I haven't searched of
>      such copiers that can map nested classes (deep property copiers). I
>      would only rely on propertyNames which I can say is not reliable
>      enough and reflection is quite slow.

Because still `XSD.exe` is widely used for generating `C#` classes, the conflict in `namespaces`, `classes`, `enumerations` and others were solved (in a way) using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) - a nuget package object-to-object mapper with a lot of features.

Still learning and exploring how to use this library, but I am still open for answers.